# Value of type ' ' has no subscripts - JSON data

Tags: json, swift

I have looked at the other answers for similar questions to this but can not find one that explains why this is coming up when requesting data from API. I am mostly confused because the error occurs when I copy the path from the JSON. After reading the error code and the documentation, I think it is something to do with an expected dictionary but found an array instead. I don't understand how to fix this when the data is coming from an API request.

Here is the JSON data that I am aiming to pull from:

[image: JSON Data]

Here is a picture of the error:
[image: Error image]

Here the code I have so far:

```
import Foundation


struct VaccineManager {
   
let vaccineURL = "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/api/v1/data?filters=areaType=overview&structure=%7B%22areaType%22:%22areaType%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22areaCode%22:%22areaCode%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22:%22newPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22,%22newPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByPublishDate%22:%22newPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByPublishDate%22,%22cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22:%22cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22,%22cumPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByPublishDate%22:%22cumPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByPublishDate%22%7D&format=json"

func performRequest(vaccineURL: String){
    if let url = URL(string: vaccineURL) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            
            if let safeData = data {
                self.parseJASON(vaccineData: safeData)
                
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
        
    }
}

func parseJASON(vaccineData: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do{
   let decodedData =  try decoder.decode(VaccineData.self, from: vaccineData)
        print(decodedData.data[0].cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And this is the code from the other file I have to for the data:

```
import Foundation

struct VaccineData: Decodable {
    let data: VaccineDataObject
}

struct VaccineDataObject: Decodable {
    let cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate: Int
    let date: String
}
```

I hope that all makes sense. Also, please tell me if I am being too detailed.

Comment: It says "cumPeople" instead of "numPeople". That might potentially be your problem.

Comment: EDIT: I guess "cum" is correct. I guess if you live long enough you'll see everything.

Comment: @ecg8 I expect "cumPeople..." is "cumulative people" rather than "number of people." This definitely matches what the provided URL returns.

Comment: BTW, the detail level here is perfect. We generally prefer the data and error messages to be given in text form rather than in images (and you may get complaints about that), but it was perfectly clear.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @RobNapier. Is there somewhere I can find out how to write the JSON data as text rather than an image?

Comment: You would cut and paste the JSON, just like code (by indenting or by surrounding in three-backticks). The above screenshot looks like VisualCode? (in which case, you can definitely just cut-and-paste). If you put the URL into a web browser, it'll also give you the JSON as text. You can then format it with something like https://jsonlint.com before posting it (so it's not one long line). Or in Swift `print(String(data: vaccineData, encoding: .utf8))`. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct definition is incorrect. It says there's a single value in `data`, but you have an array:

```
struct VaccineData: Decodable {
    let data: VaccineDataObject
}
```

Should be:

```
struct VaccineData: Decodable {
    let data: [VaccineDataObject]
}
```

You may find [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io) helpful here. It will take JSON and write decoding structs for you automatically. (Though it looks like you are pulling out such a small part, that it may be easier to hand-write as you have.)

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. THANK YOU so much!